# Retrieve a coupon associated with a checkout session during the stripe webhook named payment_intent.succeeded

Tags: stripe-payments

I created a payment session with `stripe` with the `AllowPromotionCodes` option set to true. Once the payment is done, I would like to retrieve the associated discount coupon (if it exists) in the `payment_intent.succeeded` webhook. I have the impression that this is not possible and I don't understand why. If this is the case, is there a way to get around this problem?

Edit:
I think this [link](https://support.stripe.com/questions/support-for-coupons-using-payment-intents-api) is part of the answer but I don't really understand what stripe proposes as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's a Checkout Session, you should listen to the `checkout.session.completed` event and look at [amount_discount](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-total_details-amount_discount) for the discounted amount. Once the Checkout Session is discounted, everything on `payment_intent.succeeded` will be the post discounted value and doesn't contain coupon information.

Comment: Indeed, once `total_details.breakdown.discounts` expanded inside `checkout.session.completed` webhook, I can have all the information about promotion code and coupon. Do I still have to listen to the `payment_intent.succeeded` event to know if the payment was successful or is the `checkout.session.completed` event enough? Thanks a lot

Comment: No `checkout.session.completed` should already indicates the payment was successful. You can test in Test mode.

Comment: My session response has no `breakdown` in `total_details`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a function that handles checkout completed, you can do this, in my case this is typescript

```js
async function handleCheckoutCompleted(event: Stripe.Event): Promise<void> {
  const charge = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session;
  const breakdown = charge.total_details?.breakdown
  if (breakdown) {
    for (const discount of breakdown.discounts) {
      const info = discount.discount;
      /**
       * this is a discount object with the coupon
       * see https://docs.stripe.com/api/discounts/object#discount_object-coupon
       */
      const coupon = info.coupon
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to get the coupon(s) used during chekcout.